# Azure Workbook - Authenticate to Azure Resources

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel, azure-notebooks

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6oyq.png)

Having an issue with this spot, 'Authentication to Azure Resources' not sure where I should define workspace. I thought that was covered in line 2.

- I tried adding the workspace ID

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming the notebook you are running is https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel-Notebooks/blob/85b5422ec527c88b855ce4e95f2587e27a7257d9/machine-learning-notebooks/MasqueradingProcessNameAnomaly.ipynb

Your error states:

> name 'Workspace' is not defined

This would suggest that the cells which define workspace hasn't been run. I can see that the first code cells run:

```
from azureml.core import Workspace, LinkedService
```

it is most likely you have missed these steps. Make sure you run the cells in order otherwise you may have unintended consequences like you have experienced.

Alistair